# Run Nopcommerce on console application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, nopcommerce

I want to use NopCommerce libraries for a console project (for migrate data transfer).
I create a console project and add the base libraries (Nop.Core, Nop.Data, Nop.Service, Nop.Web.Freamework) to it, I also copy the App_Data folder.
I also use Class *Startup.cs* to run the project

```
namespace Nop.Console
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => webBuilder
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration(config =>
        {
            config
                .AddJsonFile(NopConfigurationDefaults.AppSettingsFilePath, true, true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>())
    .Build();

            var engine = EngineContext.Create();
            var cs = engine.Resolve<ICategoryService>();

            System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

But *engine.Resolve();* return null;

Any idea?

Comment: You have to add permission to app data and other folders  as well exactly as mentioned on documentations and it works fine did it for nopCommerce V 4.5 and works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if this is the best solution, but at least works for me for NopCommerce 4.40.4. The code in my Console application is following:

```
/// <summary>
/// EngineContextInitializer
/// </summary>
public static class EngineContextInitializer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Runs this instance.
    /// </summary>
    public static async Task<IHost> RunAsync()
    {
        string[] args = Array.Empty<string>();
        var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => webBuilder
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration(config =>
                {
                    config
                        .AddJsonFile(NopConfigurationDefaults.AppSettingsFilePath, true, true)
                        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
                })
                .UseStartup<Startup>())
            .Build();

        //start the program, a task will be completed when the host starts
        await host.StartAsync();
        return host;
    }
}
```

The usage of EngineContextInitializer is following:

```
private async Task GetProductById(int id)
{
    using var host = await EngineContextInitializer.RunAsync();
    IEngine engine = EngineContext.Current;
    var productService = engine.Resolve<IProductService>();
    var product = await productService.GetProductByIdAsync(id);
    await host.StopAsync();
}
```

So what does make the difference between your and mine code?
I'm running the code:

```
await host.StartAsync();
```

Most importantly I'm disposing IHost after I got the product from IProductService.
On the line is the difference:

```
var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
```

And 1 more thing, you don't need to call EngineContext.Create(), because if you check the class and Current getter you will see the following code:

```
/// <summary>
    /// Gets the singleton Nop engine used to access Nop services.
    /// </summary>
    public static IEngine Current
    {
        get
        {
            if (Singleton<IEngine>.Instance == null)
            {
                Create();
            }

            return Singleton<IEngine>.Instance;
        }
    }
```

Please don't forget to dispose IHost as it implements IDisposable to avoid memory leaks.

Disclaimer: I'm not part of NopCommerce dev team, usage is at your own risk. Please follow official NopCommerce documentation or response on the topic on their website (documentation, forum or GitHub).